# Partitions of $\{1,2, \dots , n\}$ into $k$ nonempty subsets with known length for each subset.

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I appreciate if you can help me with a math problem.

While I know the number of partitions of $\{1,2, \dots , n\}$ into $k$ nonempty subsets is "Stirling numbers of the second kind", $S(n,k)$; I want to calculate the number of partitions of $\{1,2, \dots , n\}$ into $k$ nonempty subsets with known length for each subset.

For instance, the number of partitions of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into $2$ nonempty subsets is $S(4,2)=7$; however, with the length of the subsets equal to $2$ and $2$, this number becomes $C(4,2)/2=3$ or with the length of the subsets equal to $3$ and $1$, this number becomes $C(4,1)=4$.

I appreciate if you inform me of any systematic way or formula to calculate this number for a general case of $n, k$ and $\{L_1,L_2,\dots,L_k\}$ while $L_k$ is the length for the $k-$th subset and it is obvious that sum$(L_1,L_2,\dots,L_k)=n$.

Thank you.

Comment: Given an $n$-element set $X$, and a sequence $\left(k_1, k_2, k_3, \ldots\right)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying $1 k_1 + 2 k_2 + 3 k_3 + \cdots = n$. The number of partitions of $X$ set into several subsets, of which $k_1$ many have size $1$, a further $k_2$ many have size $2$, a further $k_3$ many have size $3$, etc. is $\dfrac{n!}{\left(1!^{k_1} 2!^{k_2} 3!^{k_3} \cdots\right) \left(k_1! k_2! k_3! \cdots\right)}$. (The infinite products make sense because all but finitely many of their factors equal $1$.)

Comment: Hint to the proof: WLOG assume $X = \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$. Each permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ gives rise to such a partition of $X$, namely as follows: Write out the elements $\sigma\left(1\right), \sigma\left(2\right), \ldots, \sigma\left(n\right)$ in a line, and then separate them by dividers so that the first $k_1$ blocks have size $1$, the next $k_2$ blocks have size $2$, the next $k_3$ blocks have size $3$, etc.. Finally, consider each block as a set. Thus, you get a partition. The question is only: how many different permutations $\sigma$ give rise to the same partition?

Comment: Thanks a lot darij, this is exactly what I was looking for.